# Merging two datasets of different lenghts by Date

Tags: r, date, merge

I want to merge two datasets of different length, looking like this

d1:

```
         Datum  Zeit      LV     RNG
1   2013-01-23 11:30 253.230 482.090
2   2013-01-23 12:00 347.819 474.010
3   2013-01-23 12:30 340.658 441.930
4   2013-01-23 13:00 295.011 447.755
5   2013-01-23 13:30 217.277 409.965
6   2013-01-23 14:00 258.941 363.385
7   2013-01-23 14:30 233.370 316.940
8   2013-01-23 18:30  -3.997 -32.385
9   2013-01-23 19:00  -6.464 -36.930
10  2013-01-23 19:30 -22.243 -29.815
11  2013-01-23 20:00 -15.984 -19.665
12  2013-01-23 20:30 -10.047 -17.840
13  2013-01-23 21:00 -15.283 -30.405
14  2013-01-23 23:00 -22.244 -22.065
15  2013-01-23 23:30 -31.404 -30.485
16  2013-01-24 00:00 -38.180 -33.575
17  2013-01-24 00:30 -25.143 -30.015
18  2013-01-24 01:00 -13.473 -22.780
19  2013-01-25 07:00   2.299  42.930
20  2013-01-25 07:30  57.983  96.795
```

and d2:

```
        Datum        Klasse
   [1,] "2013-01-23" "5"   
   [2,] "2013-01-24" "5"   
   [3,] "2013-01-25" "2"
```

I want to merge d1 and d2 to add the "Klasse"- value for each day in the column "Datum", meaning I want the "Klasse"- value for each specific day repeated for all registrations of that day in the occurrence data.

I have tried this code

```
result <- merge(d1, d2, by = "Datum", all.x = TRUE)
```

But all I get are NA -values in the new column (the "Klasse"-column). Is anything missing in the code?

Comment: Code works fine for me, this is not reproducible, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Actually you just need `merge(dat1, dat2)`.

Comment: `d2` is not a `data.frame`, it's a `matrix`. As such, your `Klasse` and `Datum` are both strings, not sure if that's a problem. It might be insightful for you to post the output of `dput(d1)` and `dput(d2)` (in code blocks in the question) so that we can see if there are other non-obvious issues with the data structure. The way R *prints* objects on the console does not always provide a clear idea of how it is actually structured (including each column's `class`, etc).

Comment: @r2evans I successfully `merge`d data frame and matrix as shown in OP, seems it doesn't matter, they really need to state a reproducible example.

Comment: I'm not saying it can't work, but the fact that it's a matrix means that assumptions on data `class` are likely not correct. Also, while less likely, `Date`-class objects can be fractional yet R will show them in the day-aligned format; merging on `Date`-on-`character` columns should generally be fine, but I find it's "accepting slop" to not be explicit about classes, especially merge-keys. My guess is that there's a mistake earlier in the processing of `d2` that results in it being converted from a `data.frame` to a matrix, so that step should be found and fixed. *Lots* of inference :-)